# Infragistics UltraWinGrid select newly added row

Tags: c#, winforms, infragistics, ultrawingrid

Im working with an Infragistics4.Win.UltraWinGrid.v16.1 data container. Let's say I just updated the DataSource and I want to make that row (it does show up when the DataSource is updated) active, as in it scrolls to that row and selects it. Currently I have the following faulty implementation:

```
private void SelectByID(int searchId)
{
    ISelectionManager selectionManager = grdProjects;

    foreach (UltraGridRow row in grdProjects.Rows)
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["StagingID"].Value) == searchId)
        {
            selectionManager.ActivateItem(row);
            row.Activate();
            if (grdProjects.ActiveRowScrollRegion.IsActiveScrollRegion)
                grdProjects.ActiveRowScrollRegion.ScrollRowIntoView(row);
            break;
        }
    }
}

private void _createProjectDialog_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    CreateProjectDialog send = (CreateProjectDialog)sender;
    if (send.SetAsCurrent)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        //refresh grid and set current proj
        _stagingProjects.Add(send.StagingProject);
        grdProjects.Rows.Refresh(RefreshRow.ReloadData);
        SelectedProject = ApplicationContext.Instance.Project.StagingProject;
        SelectByID(SelectedProject.StagingID); 
    }
}
```

**Note** that I added the two lines of code:

```
row.Activate();
if(grdProjects.ActiveRowScrollRegion.IsActiveScrollRegion)
```

The `IsActiveScrollRegion` condition passes, but the row is still not selected in the grid after execution.

Thank you for any assistance!

Comment: Note that the intended row always ends up at the bottom of the grid, unselected.

Answer (score 2):

In case you would like to select specific row simply use `row.Selected = true;` and in case you would like to activate specific row simply use `row.Activated = true;`Presumably you know the difference between these two and I shortly explained it in the code comments. Here is an simple form example.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private DataSet _dataSet = new DataSet();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        InitializeDataSet(_dataSet);
    }

    private void SelectByID(int searchId)
    {
        ISelectionManager selectionManager = this.ultraGrid1;

        foreach (UltraGridRow row in this.ultraGrid1.Rows)
        {
            if (Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["ID"].Value) == searchId)
            {
                if (ultraGrid1.ActiveRowScrollRegion.IsActiveScrollRegion)
                {
                    ultraGrid1.ActiveRowScrollRegion.ScrollRowIntoView(row);

                    // Activating and selecting are two different things.
                    // Activating the row draws dotted border around it.
                    // Selecting the row highlights it with blue color by default.
                    row.Activated = true;
                    row.Selected = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void ultraButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var dataSourceRows = _dataSet.Tables[0].Rows;
        var dataRow = dataSourceRows.Add(new object[] { dataSourceRows.Count });

        SelectByID(dataSourceRows.Count - 1);
    }

    private void InitializeDataSet(DataSet dataSet)
    {
        var dataTable = dataSet.Tables.Add();

        dataTable.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));

        for (int index = 0; index <= 100; index++)
        {
            dataTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { index });
        }

        this.ultraGrid1.DataSource = dataTable;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks alot for the response Ivaylo, but this does not solve my problem. The effect of your logic is the same as before (the first row in the grid is selected).

Comment: That's strange. Somewhere, something prevents selecting the last row in your application. To simplify the code a little bit. You do not have to explicitly refresh the data source if it is bound to IBinding source object such as DataSet, DataTable, IBindingList etc. The other thing is that you do not need to scroll to the newly added row explicitly either, because when the row is selected, the view will be scrolled automatically for you. Remove these lines and see what would happen and also try to reproduce my form to verify that in simplified scenario it actually works.

Comment: The data structure is a `List`, perhaps I should try changing it to a DataTable as you suggest. As such, right now the only way the newly added row shows up is through the call to explicitly Refresh `(RefreshRow.ReloadData)`

Comment: The selection has nothing to have with the data source as far as the UI is aware that something happened and can react appropriately. At least are you able to activate a row? If so, then set `ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Override.SelectTypeRow = SelectType.None;
         ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Override.ActiveRowAppearance.BackColor = ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.DefaultSelectedBackColor;` and it will always look that the activated row is the same as the selected one. There will be no need to select explicitly a row, but just activate it and let the appearance do the illusion of highlighting it.